# Reading text from a text file in python

Tags: python, text-files

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to import text from a text file easily or at least a memorable method. I am trying to make a program that insults the user (for school), that brings in a word/s from one text file, adds another word/s from the second file and the final word/s from  the third text file...

I am having trouble finding a way of coding to do this...I have the random number up and running to pick the text I just need to know how to access strings or text in a text file.

Comment: `text = open("file.txt").read()` perhaps?

Comment: How large are the textfiles?  If it's a relatively small list of insults, you could just store the data in lists ...

Comment: The text files are not that big...about 50 words, but our teacher asked to import them from external text-files and he is reluctant to teach us.

Comment: Also, be careful saying `import` -- `import` is a statement that executes python code (unless it was already `import`ed) and assigning the "result" to a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `with` statement. It takes care of closing the file for you.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with line
```

Or read the data into directly into a list:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = list(f)
# do something with lines
```